Is $\sum _{n=0} ^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2(2n+3) \binom{n-1/2}{n}} = G - \frac{1}{2}$?
Wolfram Mathematica claims that
$$\sum _{n=0} ^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2(2n+3) \binom{n-1/2}{n}} = G - 1/2$$
where $G$ is the Catalan constant.
I can't figure out how to prove that. I found a similar expression in an article by David Bradley called Representations of Catalan's Constant, it's
$$\sum _{n=0} ^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2 \binom{n-1/2}{n}} = 2G$$
so I presume the top one could be reduced to the bottom one? But how...?

Define:
$$f(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{(2n+1)^2 \binom{n-1/2}{n}} = \sum_{n=0} ^{\infty} C_n$$
Using the definition for generalized hypergeometric functions, we can find the hypergeometric form of this series (because all the coefficients are rational functions of $n$).
$$C_0 = 1$$
$$\frac{C_{n+1}}{C_n} = \frac{(n+1)\left(n+1/2 \right)^2}{\left(n+3/2 \right)^2} \frac{\binom{n-1/2}{n}}{\binom{n+1/2}{n+1}} \frac{x}{n+1}$$
It's easy to check that:
$$\frac{\binom{n-1/2}{n}}{\binom{n+1/2}{n+1}}=\frac{n+1}{n+1/2}$$
So the ratio simplifies to:
$$\frac{C_{n+1}}{C_n} = \frac{(n+1)^2\left(n+1/2 \right)}{\left(n+3/2 \right)^2} \frac{x}{n+1}$$
Which means that the function we defined is:
$$f(x) ={_3F_2} \left(1,1,\frac12; \frac32, \frac32; x \right)$$

Now our task is to simplify this hypergeometric function.
We can use the integral formula (see Wikipedia link above) to reduce it:
$$f(1)=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}} {_2F_1} \left(1,1; \frac32; t \right) $$
The function inside the integral is reduced to $\sin^{-1} \sqrt{t}$ (Wolfram Alpha helped here, but it's possible to find out from definition).
$${_2F_1} \left(1,1; \frac32; t \right)=\frac{\sin^{-1} \sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{t}\sqrt{1-t}}$$
$$f(1)=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{\sin^{-1} \sqrt{t}}{t\sqrt{1-t}}  dt$$
Substitute $t=y^2$:
$$f(1)=\int_0^1 \frac{\sin^{-1} (y)}{y \sqrt{1-y^2}} dy$$
Let's transform the integral:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\sin^{-1} (y)}{y \sqrt{1-y^2}} dy=\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-y^2} \frac{\sin^{-1} (y)}{y} dy+\int_0^1 \frac{y\sin^{-1} (y)}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} dy$$
The second term can be easily integrated by parts:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{y\sin^{-1} (y)}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} dy = -\sqrt{1-y^2} \sin^{-1} (y) \Bigg|_0^1 +  1=1$$
So we obtained the following result:
$$\color{blue}{\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-y^2} \frac{\sin^{-1} (y)}{y} dy = f(1) - 1}$$

Now let's prove that our series is equal to:
$$g(1)=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-y^2} \frac{\sin^{-1} (y)}{y} dy$$
Define:
$$g(x)=\sum _{n=0} ^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{(2n+1)^2(2n+3) \binom{n-1/2}{n}} = \sum_{n=0} ^{\infty} C_n$$
$$C_0 = \frac{1}{3}$$
$$\frac{C_{n+1}}{C_n} = \frac{(n+1)\left(n+1/2 \right)^2\left(n+3/2 \right)}{\left(n+3/2 \right)^2\left(n+5/2 \right)} \frac{\binom{n-1/2}{n}}{\binom{n+1/2}{n+1}} \frac{x}{n+1}$$
$$\frac{C_{n+1}}{C_n} = \frac{(n+1)^2\left(n+1/2 \right)}{\left(n+3/2 \right)\left(n+5/2 \right)} \frac{x}{n+1}$$
Which means that the original function is:
$$g(x) =\frac{1}{3} {_3F_2} \left(1,1,\frac12; \frac32, \frac52; x \right)$$
And the series in question:
$$g(1)=\frac{1}{3} {_3F_2} \left(1,1,\frac12; \frac32, \frac52; 1 \right)$$
Using the integral reduction formula from Wikipedia, we get:
$$g(1)=\frac{1}{4} \int_0^1 \frac{1-t}{\sqrt{t}} {_2F_1} \left(1,1; \frac32; t \right) dt$$
Same substitutions as above give us:
$$g(1)=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-y^2} \frac{\sin^{-1} (y)}{y} dy$$
Which means that if:
$$f(1)=2G$$
Then:
$$\color{blue}{g(1)=\frac{f(1)-1}{2}=G-\frac{1}{2}}$$

Notice also another important thing.
If you define:
$$F(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^2 \binom{n-1/2}{n}}$$
$$G(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n+3}}{(2n+1)^2(2n+3) \binom{n-1/2}{n}}$$
It follows that:
$$G(x)=\int F(x) dx$$

I actually didn't know about the integral transform. Your explanation was very clear, thank you!

Going from binomila coeffcients to gamma function, if you consider
$$S(x)=\sum _{n=0} ^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^2(2n+3) \binom{n-1/2}{n}}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{4}\sum _{n=0} ^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{(2 n+1) \,\Gamma
   \left(n+\frac{5}{2}\right)}\, x^{2n+1}$$ Differentiate
$$S'(x)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{4}\sum _{n=0} ^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{5}{2}\right)}\, x^{2n}$$ which happens to be (thanks to $\text{CAS}$)
$$S'(x)=\frac 1 {x^2}-\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2} }{x^3}\sin ^{-1}(x)$$  For the second integral,
$$x=\sin(t)\quad \implies\quad \int \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2} }{x^3}\sin ^{-1}(x)=\int t \cot ^2(t) \csc (t)\,dt$$ Integration by parts and the tangent half-angle substitution give the result for the antiderivative. Back to $x$, recmbine the two integrals to remove the singularity and use the bounds for the final result.
